# How to print txt ['text'] in canvas in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to print the text of

```
txt=canvas.create_text (...,text='this is some text')
```

I want the program to print **'this is some text '** I used

```
print (txt['text'])
```

it shows an error: `int object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2):

`canvas.create_text` returns an integer. That is why you get the error `int object is not subscriptable`.

You can use the `itemcget` method to get the value of an attribute of an object on the canvas. The first argument is a tag, or the id returned from one of the `create_` methods. The second argument is the name of the attribute.

In your specific example it would look like this:

```
print(canvas.itemcget(txt, "text"))
```